# Different Project Type in a Single Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websites

I have developed a website in asp.net and I have some additional tasks, improvements to develop. In order to get experience in asp.net/mvc, I want to create an admin panel using asp.net mvc.

**Is this a logical next step?**

---

P.S. The project is small and 20% of the website is mine, so there are not any restrictions. There is no problem if I do not meet deadlines! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly common to transition from one web framework over to another, doing new development in the once and future framework and migrating the older projects as there is time (frequently, there is never time).

It would generally be a little more frowned upon to maintain two web applications written in the same language running different frameworks as a planned way of life--in most corporate settings, homogeneity in framework choice is encouraged.

That said, for smaller projects or personal projects, I would not really worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion between those two similiar technologies are very long, and no one is better than other, only is for two different things.

On the ASP.NET WebForms (classic ASP.NET) you have a lot of controls, an extense collection of controls which you can pick, drag and drop and configure, its really fast but you have a lot of impediments when you want to manage at lower level the html of the page, and the code are very disordered.

On ASP.NET MVC you a lot of control on your html and you can do almost anything, i mean anything with styles and html but mostly you need to do by hand. But one of the great advantages of MVC is de order of the code, you always have ordered solution, projects, and clases, its a really great pattern.

Finally do not care to have different projects with different technologies, its a common case, most than you think, and if you think that MVC is better for the new project go ahead, its a really good choice.

I'll hope this help you. I'm a teacher of web development on the course 10264